# Presenting Modal View Keeps on Failing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I keep getting this warning and no matter what I try I'm not sure how to resolve it.

```
Attempt to present <LoginViewController: 0x1f0b5010> on <ViewController: 0x1dda1670> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I don't have a segue in my storyboard since, I'm calling the modal view programmatically:

```
//Load Login View if no username is found
NSLog(@"No username found");
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
LoginViewController *loginView = (LoginViewController *)
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
[self presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here's an image of my storyboard:

[image]

Thank you!!!

Comment: Have you write this code in ViewDidload?

Comment: I had the same issue i called method in ViewDidLoad if you too then please try in viewDidAppear: and check ?

Comment: You have to add the relation link between the seques in storyboard.

Comment: Here the problem is not the place you have put this code, Error says "view is not in the window hierarchy!" Maybe chad is correct

Comment: NO if you write the code in ViewDidiLoad than the previous view is not even loaded and we are trying to present another view.

Comment: actually placement of code can also be a problem because the view controller's view is not in the window hierarchy until the ViewDidAppear: methood is called

Comment: DownVoter warm welcome you but follow rules put the comment first on my answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to present view in `ViewDidload`, it will generate error.

If you want to use that than you can use `performselector` and than call this code on some delay.

Comment: I did have it in viewDidload, let me try moving it to ViewDidAppear.

Comment: And yes you can also try [self performSelector:@selector(Test) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

Answer (score 0):

if you have this code to present a modal view controller in the `viewDidLoad` method. then move it to  `viewDidAppear:` method.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the "loginView" as global in either .h or extension in .m file as given and synthesis it.

```
@property(strong, nonatomic)LoginViewController *loginView;
```

It will resolve your issue :)